# expandableListView listeners not working using a particular layout

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

ExpandableListView does not work using the following layout. OnGroupClickListener is never called when user clicks.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
android:focusable="false">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:focusable="false"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/buttons_group_rowIV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/radar_settings_gafas_led_off" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buttons_group_row_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:text="@string/interiorLED"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/buttons_group_row_SW"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But if I use the following layout all works fine. The only difference is the Switch Widget, that now is a ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/buttons_group_rowIV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/radar_settings_gafas_led_off" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buttons_group_row_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:text="@string/interiorLED"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttons_group_noSW_rowIV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/radar_settings_gafas_led_off" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok. Solved.Need to add: android:focusable="false" to Switch: